# Backend of the WordPress.com

Tags: php, wordpress.com-hosting, scale

It has been known that PHP is under an impression that its a web low performer. However, the size of WordPress.com says otherwise. Does anyone knows why WordPress.com blogs scale so well even though its in PHP? Where is the PHP's maximum. Lets say capacity of simultaneous user access?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress certainly can scale. Wordpress.com alone served [14.6 billion pages](http://en.wordpress.com/stats/) last month. The key is that they had hundreds of servers so that they can widely distribute the load. Since they have a more tightly controlled platform, which helps them ensure that they don't have badly written code slowing things down. But in the end, a lot of things don't have a limit to how large they can scale, as long as you give enough resources to it.